# moving div right left continously in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to move a `div` continuously left and right on page load. But what I did is moving on click. And that's what I don't want. Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<a href="" class="left">left</a> | <a href="" class="right">right</a>
<br /><br />
<div id="foo" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute"></div>

<script> 
$('.right').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#foo').css({ 'right': '0px', 'left': '' }).animate({
        'right' : '30px'    
    });                    
});

$('.left').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#foo').css({ 'right': '', 'left': '0px' }).animate({
        'left' : '30px'
    });                    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `auto` values are not correctly automatically assigned by jQuery or the browser.

Use something like this:

```js
$('.right').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#foo').css({ 'right': window.innerWidth - $('#foo').position().left - $('#foo').width(), 'left': 'auto' }).animate({
    'right' : '30px'
  });
});

$('.left').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#foo').css({ 'left': $('#foo').position().left, 'right': 'auto' }).animate({
    'left' : '30px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="left">left</a> | <a href="" class="right">right</a>
<br /><br />
<div id="foo" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute"></div>
```

As your question says, if you want it to automatically do either, on page load, do this:

```js
$(function () {
  function a() {
    $('#foo').css({ 'right': window.innerWidth - $('#foo').position().left - $('#foo').width(), 'left': 'auto' }).animate({
      'right' : '30px'
    }, function () {
      $('#foo').css({ 'left': $('#foo').position().left, 'right': 'auto' }).animate({
        'left' : '30px'
      }, a);
    });
  }
  a();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br /><br />
<div id="foo" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with  [`CSS animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

```css
#foo {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  animation: leftRight linear 3s infinite alternate;
  
}

@keyframes leftRight {
  to {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```